# Как добавить к базе данных число через сутки?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram

Есть бот в телеграмме и база данных (SQLite)
Пользователь совершил действие (например: написал боту "Бонус"), у пользователя в базе данных отнимается 1, как сделать, чтобы через 24 часа пользователю добавлялось 1?

Comment: Хранить операции изменения отдельно и не учитывать их, если их давность больше 24 часов.

Answer (score 0):

Если используете `asyncio`, то можно сделать через `loop.create_task` с функцией, в которой сначала отнимаете 1, потом через `asyncio.sleep(86400)` добавляете её обратно.